# How to return Service Now tickets list to AWS Lex from AWS Lambda?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-lex, servicenow-rest-api

From Lex ChatBot User will ask give me `ServiceNow` Ticket list.

I am trying to get the Service Now tickets list from Service Now by Calling an `ServiceNow` API from `AWS Lambda`, I am getting the results (Tickets list) in Lambda function, but how to send Ticket list from `AWS Lambda` to `AWS LEX`.

I used `PYSNOW` library to get the data from `ServiceNow` to `ALWS Lambda`.
How to send SNow ticket list to Lex from Lambda?

Answer (score 0):

In your Lambda function you need to build and return a return object that matches with the format expected by Lex.

You can read about it in the documentation here:- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/lambda-input-response-format.html#using-lambda-response-format

Sample apps are available on Github as well:- https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-lambda-developer-guide/tree/main/sample-apps